# Problem with stored properties in extensions in project from GitHub

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, collectionview

I'm learning how to implement great CollectionViewPagingLayout templates in my project.
This one: https://github.com/amirdew/CollectionViewPagingLayout

First I specify which template to use (now I use "invertedCylinder") - and this part works well:

```
extension MovieCollectionViewCell: ScaleTransformView {
    var scaleOptions: ScaleTransformViewOptions {
        .layout(.invertedCylinder)   
    }
}
```

The problem appears when I try to modify the template. There is an extension, written by the creator of the  Layout:

```
extension YourCell: ScaleTransformView {
    var scaleOptions = ScaleTransformViewOptions(
        minScale: 0.6,
        scaleRatio: 0.4,
        translationRatio: CGPoint(x: 0.66, y: 0.2),
        maxTranslationRatio: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 0
    )
}
```

I have tried to get rid of stored properties error and modify the code:

```
extension MovieCollectionViewCell: ScaleTransformView {
    var scaleOptionsDetailed: ScaleTransformViewOptions {
        minScale: 0.6,
        scaleRatio: 0.4,
        translationRatio: CGPoint(x: 0.66, y: 0.2),
        maxTranslationRatio: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 0)
    }
}
```

But this gives me more errors:

1. Redundant conformance of 'MovieCollectionViewCell' to protocol 'ScaleTransformView'
2. Cannot find 'minScale' in scope
3. Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

I understand that this is a question about basics. But it is already the second day im trying to solve the issue and would be very grateful for a guidance.

Comment: For reference, the code above is give as a sample in the repo's [HOW_TO_USE_UIKIT.md](https://github.com/amirdew/CollectionViewPagingLayout/blob/0d0d78d13366a4a1737729b643d0adee61143924/HOW_TO_USE_UIKIT.md) file, and not as actual code. It's either a mistake on the part of the author, or just written as an extension to give some context as to where this property is going, but either way, it will not compile.

Comment: Can you please give a tip how to improve it? I tried to create computed properties, but with them xCode fails to understand "minScale" and other parameters

Comment: You'll need to share the code you tried and the error you're getting (you can update your question with the code). [`ScaleTransformViewOptions`](https://github.com/amirdew/CollectionViewPagingLayout/blob/3aeb224d1efc0d7cd65f7056e3e99076f9addbde/Lib/Scale/ScaleTransformViewOptions.swift) does appear to take these options, so without other info it's impossible to tell what might be going on.

Comment: I have updated the post - can you please take a look

Comment: You haven't quite correctly converted this into a computed property: your syntax for the property declaration is correct (`var scaleOptionsDetailed: ScaleTransformViewOptions { ... }`) but the _contents_ are not valid Swift. `minScale`, `scaleRatio`, etc. all need to be inside of an initializer call (`ScaleTransformViewOptions(minScale: 0.6, ...)`). See this Gist for the appropriate syntax: https://gist.github.com/itaiferber/53238d86d699025e751f5f247bdefe43

Comment: Itai, thank you very much for your help! It works perfectly now.

Comment: Excellent! Happy it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know why that repo includes stored properties on an extension. That is illegal and will likely always be illegal.

You could convert your variable scaleOptions to a computed property. To do that get rid of the equals sign. Then every time you reference that property it will run the code in the closure and generate a new value.

It is also possible to fake stored properties for extensions using associated values from the Objective-C runtime, but that is considered a hack and probably not a great idea.

Comment: Based on the context of the given sample (it's just sample code given in a Markdown file), I'd also add that it seems that the original author might be intending for code consumers to add `scaleOptions` as an actual stored property on their type, just perhaps not in an extension. So, if you own and control the a class inheriting from `ScaleTransformView`, you can add `scaleOptions` as a stored property in the original definition of your type.